# Accent marks on WPS Office in Kubuntu 18.04 doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support, wps-office

Recently I installed WPS Office (Kinsoft) over Kubuntu 18.04.

After follow some guides I got changed the default language and grammar corrector to Spanish (my native language). All things works fine except the **accent marks**.

I'm using three different keyboard distributions:

1. Spanish [Spain]
2. English [US]
3. English [US] (with dead keys)

Normally, With the 1st distribution I should be capable to write words with accents like (país, nación, exámenes, etc.), but currently it isn't possible.

With the 3rd distribution I can write accents using a combination with the **'Alt' key** (Eg.: Alt+a = á, Alt+n = ñ, etc.)

The goal is to write the accent marks like MS Office **character ' + vocal**.
How can I achieve this?

--

**Edit 1 [2018/07/13]**

This issue only occurs when I write documents with WPS Office or Libre Office for Linux. The accents works fine over other programs, like Firefox or G Chrome.

**Edit 2**

I found this page that illustrate more clearly what I want with the **Spanish [ES]** distribution.

http://www.farah.cl/DistribucionesDeTeclado/LatAmExt_es.html

In this table you will find all combination of keys to get all Diacritics (apologize for the table in spanish).

[image: Diacritics of Spanish [ES] Distribution]

I forgot to mention that I copied all Windows fonts to the `/usr/share/fonts/` directory.

Comment: You may have misunderstood how the keyboard layouts you have tried to use work. More details, e.g. a picture showing exactly which key you press, might help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think the post explains very well the ideas and the layouts that I've been testing. Do you want to know some specific detail?

Comment: Hmm.. Your edit fills the gap I felt, I think. You seem to know how dead keys are supposed to work. I have one idea, which you may want to test: Create an additional user, log in as that user, and check if the issue with WPS Office or LibreOffice is still present.

Comment: Doesn't pressing Alt+` (Alt+ backtick) then the vocal insert è or à or ì - depending on the vocal? I think the other shortcut is Alt+' (Alt+apostrophe) then your vocal.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I just tried your idea (new user) and got the same problem! Maybe I was not as clear as I wanted, the goal is to have the **Spanish [ES]** layout, write the accents pressing first the `apostrophe` then the `vocal`, without pressing `Alt` or anyother key.

Comment: With the Spanish layout I can do ´ followed by A to get á. In that case I use the dead_accute symbol which is two keys to the right of the L key. I can also do ` followed by A to get à. In that case I use the dead_grave symbol which is to the right of the P key. No need to press Alt. But please note that different keys are used for accute respecive grave accents.

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is very old but I have solved this problem using the following command:

```
im-config
```

Run as non-root user.

Then select ibus from the input methods list. **You will need to restart your computer for changes to take effect.**

Now the accent marks are working properly on WPS-Office...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd>. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, I found that it was related to the input bus fcitx, so I replaced it with iBus and now accents are working correctly on WPS.

LibreOffice accents worked well on both input bus servers, it was just a WPS issue.